# Cannot read property setState of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, state

I'm having a react component, which has a function with a axios call, to retrieve data.
That data is being put into an array, and that array is being send to the state.

However, when trying to set I get the error:
 Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I have bind the function in the constructor, and the setState is outside the axios call.

My code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import axios from "axios";
import { host } from "../../searchkitConfig/const_host.js";

import {
  SearchkitComponent
} from "searchkit";

export class AutoCompleteContainer extends SearchkitComponent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "suggestCallReady" : false,
      "suggestions":[]
    };
    this.suggestCall = this.suggestCall.bind();
  }
  suggestCall(){
    const query =
    {
      "_source": [
        "suggest-auteur"
      ],
      "suggest": {
        "auteur_suggest": {
          "prefix": "te",
          "completion": {
            "field": "suggest-auteur"
          }
        },
        "hoofdtitel_suggest": {
          "prefix": "te",
          "completion": {
            "field": "suggest-hoofdtitel"
          }
        },
        "imprint_suggest": {
          "prefix": "te",
          "completion": {
            "field": "suggest-imprint"
          }
        }
      }
    };

    var suggestArray = [];
    axios
      .post(host + "/_search", query, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      })
      .then( res => {
        for(var i = 0; i < res.data.suggest.auteur_suggest[0].options.length; i++){
          suggestArray.push(res.data.suggest.auteur_suggest[0].options[i].text);
        }

      });
      console.log('suggestArray:',suggestArray)
      this.setState({"suggestions":suggestArray});
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.suggestCall();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.state.suggestions.length >1 ? this.state.suggestions : "No suggestions has been found"}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `this.suggestCall = this.suggestCall.bind(this);` you need to pass `this` in `bind ` function

Comment: Oh lol.. That was stupid. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to bind it. But you have another problem: since you're calling `setState` outside the `then` callback, it will not set the state to the data you fetched. Move `setState` inside `then`.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.suggestCall = this.suggestCall.bind(this);
```

you need to pass `this` in `bind` function

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor:

```
this.suggestCall = this.suggestCall.bind(this);
```

But I would advise to refrain from this style and use arrow functions instead. The benefit is just a leaner and more readable and thus maintainable code (if I'm not mistaken), but helps a lot in the future.

So, instead of:

```
suggestCall(){
//Your code goes here
}
```

and then binding this in the constructor, you can write:

```
suggestCall = () => {
//Your code goes here
}
```

and don't need to bind this in the constructor anymore.

Quoting [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> Two factors influenced the introduction of arrow functions: shorter
>   functions and no existence of this keyword.

It further states that arrow functions have **no separate this**:

> **Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value**
>   (based on how function was called, a new object in the case of a
>   constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object
>   if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to
>   be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.
>
> An **arrow function does not have its own this**; the this value of the
>   enclosing lexical context is used i.e. **Arrow functions follow the
>   normal variable lookup rules**. So while searching for this  which is
>   not present in current scope they end up finding this from its
>   enclosing scope . Thus, in the following code, **the this within the
>   function that is passed to setInterval has the same value as this in
>   the lexically enclosing function**:

```
function Person(){

      this.age = 0;

      setInterval(() => {
        this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the Person object
      }, 1000);
    }

var p = new Person();
```

Emphasis in the quoted text from developer.mozilla.org are mine.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Kev, thanks for your answer. Should I set 'this' . inside the () or is it being bind because of the ()..? I'm getting used to the arrow functions.

Comment: No, you don't need to set it manually. Arrow functions solve the famous JavaScript this problem by design. They just bind it for you. So even if you had other arguments to your function it would become suggestCall = (argOne, argTwo) => {} and this would be bound automatically.